# perl regexp curly brackets

Tags: regex, perl

How can I match multilines between { and }. Exactly I need to match block below

```
host customerPERA {
      host-identifier option agent.circuit-id "x:y";
      fixed-address yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy;
      option routers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
      option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}
```

I have to delete that block from very huge dhcpd.conf file. 
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I forgot, I need regexp for perl..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it:

```
perl  -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/^host customerPERA[^}]*}//smg' /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

Thanks all

Comment: What about if any curly braces found inside your inputs? Might be it will not match?

Comment: @ssr1012: it's been a long time since I've configured a dhcpd server, but if I recall correctly, there aren't any instances where braces are used inside of a host definition. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your problem:

```
perl -p0i -e 's/host\s+customerPERA\s+\{[^}]+\}/host customerPERA {}/g' /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

It will replace "host customerPERA {}" on "host customerPERA {}" (with empty curly brackets)

Comment: probably need the /s multi-line also

Comment: @xxfelixxx: /s changes how `.` behaves. There's no `.` in the regex.

Comment: `/m` changes how `^` and `$` behave. It's not needed here.

Comment: I'm trying to delete that block with: perl -pi -e "s/^host customerPERA \{[^}]*\}//" /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf without success

Comment: perl -e 'open my $fh, "/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf" or die "Unable to open : $!"; my $txt = do { local $/; <$fh> }; $txt =~ s/host\s+customerPERA\s+\{([^}]+)\}//m; print $txt;'

Comment: "perl -p0i -e"
not
"perl -pi -e"

Answer (score 0):

I can do it this way:

Input:

```
host customerPERA{
       host-identifier option agent.circuit-id "x:y";
       fixed-address yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy;
       option routers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
       option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
 }
```

If this is the case to find exactly matches:

Regex Pattern:

```
 $myRegex = qw/((?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*)/;

 if($pattern=~m/host CustomerPERA\{$myRegex\}/gs)
 {
      #do it you statement here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the [single line modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#The-dot) locally with `(?s)`. 
This can give you a one line code to remove or edit what you want.

```
$string =~ s/host customerPERA \{(?s).+?\}//;
```